# openCV defect detection problem(How to make the borders neat?)

Tags: python, opencv

I want to detect dust in the circle in the image, but there is a problem in that the edges are detected even in areas that are not actually defective. I am curious to see if it helps to handle the border part.

I would like to know how to clean up the pixels of the partial parts.

[image]

Comment: You could try morphology open and close

Comment: Are you talking about erosion and dilation?

Comment: No, but they are used by open and close. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_morphology for definition. Opening and closing are just one of open or close followed by the other.

Comment: When morphology is applied, even dust is affected, making detection difficult.
Is there a way to affect only the border part?

Comment: Make a mask of just the border region that you want so that it ignores the rest.

Comment: Where are the defects and what is the object that you have? Please clarify your issue better.

Comment: The defect is a dot at 9 o'clock on the dst3 image.